# Prevent inserting duplicate data in Sqlite Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to prevent to insert a duplicated rows in SQLite, for that i'm using a unique attribute :

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String CREATETABLE = "CREATE TABLE contacts ( " +
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "name TEXT, "+
                "profil TEXT, "+
                "phone TEXT UNIQUE ,"+
                "blocked TEXT, "+
                "show TEXT , "+
                "objectid TEXT )";

        db.execSQL(CREATETABLE);
    }
```

But when I'm inserting a row with a same phone, I have an error which appears in Log :

```
E/SQLiteLog: (2067) abort at 17 in [INSERT INTO contacts(phone,name,blocked,objectid,show,profil) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)]: UNIQUE constraint failed: contacts.phone
```

Is that bad, any way to prevent that ?

```
 public void addcontact(contacts contact){



        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();


        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("name", contact.getName());
        values.put("phone", contact.getNumero());
        values.put("profil", contact.getProfil());
        values.put("show", contact.getShow());
        values.put("blocked", contact.getBlocked());
        values.put("objectid", contact.getObjectid());



        try {
            db.insertOrThrow("contacts",
                    null,
                    values);
        } catch(SQLiteException e) {
            Log.d("My App", "caught");

        }
        //db.close();
    }
```

Comment: Your `catch` is not working ? Did you see _"caught"_ on the logs ?

Comment: Yes I see Caught too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you simply want to prevent the error and effectively do nothing if the unique value already exists then use...

[insertWithOnConflict (String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues initialValues, int conflictAlgorithm)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertWithOnConflict(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20int))

...and use `CONFILCT_IGNORE` for the `conflictAlgorithm` parameter.

If you actually want to update an existing row if it already exists, you can use the same method with `CONFLICT_UPDATE` instead.

Comment: Can you please give an example ??

Comment: No because I've never used it before - I simply read the documentation which, if you click on the link, you can see for yourself. It uses exactly the same parameters as the `insertOrThrow(...)` method you are using but with the extra `conflictAlgorithm` parameter. I've explained that `CONFLICT_IGNORE` simply ignores the existing row and that `CONFLICT_UPDATE` will update it. Use whichever one you need to achieve whatever result you want - either way, it won't throw an exception.